# filtering result set using xquery on xml sql column

Tags: xml, xquery-sql

I'm having trouble figuring out how to filter this snippet of xml. I would like to get the `svcProvNbr` where the `userServiceCde = OASV`

```
<dataExtract xmlns="http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS/dataExtract.xsd">
   <shipment>
      <location lctnSeqNbr="001">
         <lctnServiceProvider>
            <userServiceCde>EASV</userServiceCde>
            <svcProvNbr>1470-000</svcProvNbr>
            <svcProvTypeCde>A</svcProvTypeCde>
         </lctnServiceProvider>
         <lctnServiceProvider>
            <userServiceCde>OASV</userServiceCde>
            <svcProvNbr>1470-000</svcProvNbr>
            <svcProvTypeCde>A</svcProvTypeCde>
         </lctnServiceProvider>
      </location>
   </shipment>
</dataExtract>
```

I have tried a couple different ways but no luck

```
xmlalliedxml.query
    ('declare namespace r = "http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS";
     data(/r:dataExtract/r:shipment/r:location[@lctnSeqNbr=sql:variable("@vcSegmentNo")]/r:lctnServiceProvider.userServiceCde[.="OASV"]/r:svcProvNbr)')
```

and

```
xmlalliedxml.query
    ('declare namespace r = "http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS";
     for $sp in /r:dataExtract/r:shipment/r:location[@lctnSeqNbr=sql:variable("@vcSegmentNo")]/r:lctnServiceProvider/r:svcProvNbr
 where $sp/r:dataExtract/r:shipment/r:location[@lctnSeqNbr=sql:variable("@vcSegmentNo")]/r:lctnServiceProvider/r:userServiceCde[.="OASV"]
 return
 $sp')
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<dataExtract xmlns="http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS/dataExtract.xsd">
 <shipment>
   <location lctnSeqNbr="001">
     <lctnServiceProvider>
       <userServiceCde>EASV</userServiceCde>
       <svcProvNbr>1470-000</svcProvNbr>
       <svcProvTypeCde>A</svcProvTypeCde>
     </lctnServiceProvider>
     <lctnServiceProvider>
       <userServiceCde>OASV</userServiceCde>
       <svcProvNbr>1470-001</svcProvNbr>
       <svcProvTypeCde>A</svcProvTypeCde>
     </lctnServiceProvider>
   </location>
 </shipment>
</dataExtract>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS' AS ns)
SELECT
    @input.value('(ns:dataExtract/ns:shipment/ns:location/ns:lctnServiceProvider[ns:userServiceCde="OASV"]/ns:svcProvNbr)[1]', 
                 'varchar(50)') AS 'Service Provider Number"
```

I modified your XML so I can keep the two entries apart, and this `SELECT` statement does indeed return `1470-001` as the value.

**Update:** to do this from a column in a table, use this code:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://dtd-sirvahub.sirva.com/xml/SCHEMA/ATS' AS ns)
SELECT
    XmlAllied.value('(ns:dataExtract/ns:shipment/ns:location/ns:lctnServiceProvider[ns:userServiceCde="OASV"]/ns:svcProvNbr)[1]', 
                 'varchar(50)') AS 'Service Provider Number"
FROM 
    dbo.AutoExtract
WHERE
    (some condition here)
```

Comment: how would i do this from a xml column, not a variable?  In this case my xml is in a column called xmlallied on a table called autoextract

Comment: @bubk: updated my answer with a sample for doing it from a column in a table

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what marc_s gave, you might want to consider using `CROSS APPLY
  TableColumn.nodes('/') as t(c)` between FROM and WHERE (with `TableColumn` being the name of column containing the XML and then the path inside the parenthesis).